# Java transparent JFrame, JVLC and java.awt.Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, transparent, jna, jvlc

I am trying to achieve an effect of transparent JFrame on top of video stream provided JVLC library.
Background is an instance of java.awt.Canvas
Foreground is my whatever JFrame with a couple of controls on it.

rootPane.setForeground(myFrame);
rootPane.setBackground(myCanvas);

JVLC uses my canvas through JNA like this
jvlc.setVideoOutput(myCanvas);
jvlc.apply();

I expect myFrame to be always transparent to myCanvas.
Any ideas how to get this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can't (reliably) mix lightweight Swing components, such as JPanel, with heavyweight native components, such as Canvas. If you want to display a JPanel, you'll have to add it (ultimately) to a JFrame or a JWindow.